# Does dynamic_cast behave as a static_cast, if there is not a single virtual function?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

In a class hierarchy without any virtual functions, will `dynamic_cast` behave as a simple `static_cast` since it doesn't have any information stored for RTTI, or it will give an error?

Comment: The question has a simple answer: try it out. The test for this particular question is trivial.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I commented to the answer given by vitaut.

Answer (score 8):

It's easy to check:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  A* a = new B();
  B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
}
```

G++ says:

```
error: cannot dynamic_cast 'a' (of type 'class A*') to type 'class B*' (source type is not polymorphic)
```

BTW for this kind of questions I find [online llvm-gcc demo](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi) useful.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks, I should have try that before asking. Wonder should I remove this question now.

Comment: Well he is casting the pointer I think which is legal and thats what dynamic_cast is meant for if the classes were using virtual functions.

Comment: Hey Thanks again for the link to compile the code online. Its really useful sometimes.